# Reducing the window width tends to hide the close button

Tags: c#, docking, avalondock

Using the `AvalonDock` library, if we reduce the window width, then the close button will become hidden. This is wrong.

Ideally it should hide the window from the right hand side, not from the left hand side.

What property should I set for achieving this?

```
layoutAnchorablemXiRegister.Title = "mXi Register";
layoutAnchorablemXiRegister.Content = mXiRegisterWindow;
layoutAnchorablemXiRegister.ContentId = "layoutAnchorablemXiRegister";
layoutAnchorablemXiRegister.FloatingWidth = 380;
layoutAnchorablemXiRegister.FloatingHeight = 560;
layoutAnchorablemXiRegister.Hiding += new EventHandler<CancelEventArgs>(layoutAnchorable_Hiding);
layoutAnchorablemXiRegister.Hide();
layoutAnchorablemXiRegister.IsVisible = false;
layoutAnchorablemXiRegister.CanAutoHide = false;
```